# C# and MySQL Connectors

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, database-permissions

Developing an application for a client that when users log off, it runs the program.

The program so far grabs all the users internet browsing history and puts it to a html file, but they want to switch to a MySQL approach

Got all the MySQL working, but at logoff, the application runs.

From my PC, i can directly connect to the MySQL Server using the credentials, and its all on local network, so no issues there.

But we get this issue flagging up...

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: historylog.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 516410a9
  Problem Signature 04: MySql.Data
  Problem Signature 05: 6.0.7.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4c75af83
  Problem Signature 07: fc
  Problem Signature 08: 64
  Problem Signature 09: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySql
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

According to people online, 0a9e means no permission to access the Server, but it is full permissions to the table it needs and actually, full permissions to the server itself

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using `MySql` via `DirectAdmin` or so, you should add `%` to the `access host` list from the correspondending database.

Comment: Its a MySQL server running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server hooked up to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yous should run

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'youruser'@'yourdomain';
```

in order to make sure your user has the correct rights.
You should also ensure that you are connecting from an authorized domain. Authorization can be granted/denied for a specific subnet. see [grant documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords)

Comment: Authorization is wildcarded for the user, the user we are using is "remote"@"%"

Comment: That is what is returned when running grants...

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*12A5766D1E225DFDD932DD27DF373F3E2F8E15C7' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `enet`.* TO 'remote'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '12A5766D1E225DFDD932DD27DF373F3E2F8E15C7' WITH GRANT OPTION 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON enet. TO 'remote'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: is the problem specific to .net apps? did you try connecting from the same machine using mysql command line with the same user?

Comment: Not sure sorry, when testing the program on my pc, it worked fine. We really cant run MySQL command line on User PCs as its a school and they are locked down.

Comment: it would be nice to know if the problem is relate to (1)your app (2).net connecting to mysql (3)the target machine. I'd try to connecting using a script on a target machine without using .net (small ruby script for instance?). Try also to connect using a simple .net console app.

Comment: Ill develop a small console based .net program that i can run on the target machine and see if i can connect.

Comment: I tried a small exe that connected and displayed data from a table, works fine from the logged on user's machine. its just on log off, it just errors. Perhaps because its running as SYSTEM instead of the user, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the database schema on mysql server, the program could not create it (like it did in your development environment). the error was caused by the generation of database schema.